# one Drawer for all screens in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

i'm new to flutter and I want to create a web app with drawer and couple of screens.
here is my `main` function and root of apps ui:

```
void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Tapchi Admin Panel',
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: bgColor,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme
              .of(context)
              .textTheme)
              .apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
          canvasColor: secondaryColor,
        ),
        home: const DashboardScreen()
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my `DashboardScreen`:

```
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my `SideMenu`:

```
class SideMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideMenu({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
      children: [
        const DrawerHeader(child: Icon(Icons.android)),
        SideMenuItem(
            title: 'dashboard',
            leadingIcon: Icons.dashboard,
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const DashboardScreen()));
              }),
        SideMenuItem(
            title: 'users',
            leadingIcon: Icons.person,
            press: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const UserScreen()));
            }),
      ],
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

my problem is when i navigate into `DashboardScreen` i lose `AppBar` and `Drawer` but I want to have them for entire application!.
in android we could solve this problem by using `NavHost`.
how can I have one `Drawer` for my whole app.
by the way i'm developing a webApp

Comment: Since both `appBar` and `drawer` are properties of a `Scaffold`, you need to add your application bar and drawer menu to every `Scaffold` in your application where you need them. You can create your own custom Scaffold widget for that purpose.

Comment: @PeterKoltai in this case when i press back i get previous drawer state which is still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do that using two `MaterialApp` widgets and a global `navigatorKey` variable. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sample();
  }
}

class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: SideMenu(),
        // use new MaterialApp to push new (sub)screens on top of that area and preserve the same drawer
        body: MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text('Home screen')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SideMenu extends Drawer {
  const SideMenu({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(child: Icon(Icons.android)),
          SideMenuItem(
              title: 'dashboard',
              leadingIcon: Icons.dashboard,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    navigatorKey.currentContext!,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const DashboardScreen()));
              }),
          SideMenuItem(
              title: 'users',
              leadingIcon: Icons.person,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    navigatorKey.currentContext!,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const UserScreen()));
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SideMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final IconData leadingIcon;
  final Function() press;

  const SideMenuItem({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.leadingIcon,
    required this.press,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(leadingIcon),
      title: Text(title),
      onTap: press,
    );
  }
}

class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Center(child: Text('Dashboard screen')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(child: Text('User screen')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```